# Adobe Flash slows down after switch user in Windows

Tags: windows, flash, internet-explorer, adobe

I'm writing automatic behaviour test to Adobe Flash Game and when I switch user in Windows (noone is logged on account but Flash process is still working), performance Adobe Flash is slowing down. Is there a way to bypass this problem.